# How to export files in Unity iOS build

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I would like to export/share a csv file in my Unity iOS build. The most satisfying functionality would be the sharing pop-up after creating a file, because I don't want to have my users search in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application//Documents (like with Application.persistentDataPath).

Is there any solution/plugin for this functionality?

Kind regards Chris

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, i use https://github.com/ChrisMaire/unity-native-sharing

After adding this as an asset, just call this function:

```
NativeShare.Share(string body, string filePath, string url, string subject, string mimeType = "text/html", bool chooser, string chooserText)
```

this supports Android & iOS - and iOS only uses the first 4 parameters - actually you can get it to work with only the filePath attribute - so if you save the csv file (under Application.persistentDataPath), you could simply call:

```
NativeShare.Share("", Application.persistentDataPath + "/myShinyCsvFile.csv", "", "", "", false, "");
```